# Start menu items without "Open file location" option to them: how to rename? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, rename, links

Just upgraded my `wsl` Ubuntu distro to 20.10 "by hand"; the start menu entry name remained "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" and I would like to rename it accordingly. How to do it?

The problem is that this is one of the start menu entries (along with e. g. Cortana, 3D viewer and several others) which do not have "Open file location" in their context menu, only "Pin to taskbar", "App settings", "Run as administrator", "Rate and review" and "Share" (and I could find nothing useful for my purpose under "App settings"). They do not even seem to come from any .lnk file, at least I cannot find such anywhere on my system (using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)). I am able to create a link to these startup entries elsewhere (say, on the desktop), and I am able to rename this desktop link, but understandably this does not affect the start menu entry in any way. Looking at properties of such newly created links, their `Target type` and `Target` is described by some obscure text which does not even entirely fit in its window:

[image]

I tried following the paths which contain these texts, there are several, but I could not find any links there to rename. As you see, "Open file location" is greyed out.

So, how can I rename such start menu entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This subject was raised in the feature request at
[Allow WSL distros to change their WSL name #4241](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4241),
but no answer was given by Microsoft.

Some articles recommend renaming the distribution at the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss{WSL-GUID?}\DistributionName`.
However, on my computer the distribution name under this key is not
the same as in the Start menu,
so this advice does not work. Even the utility `wslconfig /list`
of Microsoft is wrong about the name of my Ubuntu distribution.

Therefore I don't think that it's a good idea to force the issue,
and there is a good chance that such an attempt will cause more harm than help.

A method is described in the article
[How to backup, restore, move, install or rename your WSL installation](https://j4c0b1.medium.com/how-to-backup-restore-move-install-or-rename-your-wsl-installation-6ef79f2a0efb)
which involves duplicating the distribution under another name,
setting the duplicate as the default, and then uninstalling the old one.

The tool used is
[LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline/releases),
which is a free and open-source utility for managing WSL.

Here is the procedure (to be modified for your setup):

List installed distributions:

```
LxRunOffline.exe list
```

Export the listed distribution (say ubuntu_old):

```
LxRunOffline.exe export -n ubuntu_old -f c:/tmp/Ubuntu.tar.gz
```

To restore the full distribution under a new name:

```
LxRunOffline.exe install -n ubuntu_new -d C:\wsl\ubuntu_new -f c:/tmp/Ubuntu.tar.gz
```

Check the new distribution:

```
LxRunOffline.exe list
```

Set the new distribution as default:

```
LxRunOffline.exe sd -n ubuntu_new
```

Uninstall the old distribution:

```
LxRunOffline.exe ui -n ubuntu_old
```

Keep in mind that the WSL listed name is unrelated to what is really running inside
the distribution.

Comment: Seems like I have to accept this one. Very far from satisfactory but there does not seem to be any better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Start -> Run -> `regedit`

In regedit you search for "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" and you have several places where you can change "DisplayName" and "AppName" to one you like.

By trial and error method or changing all the occurrences you finally get what you want.

Make system restore point first to eventually restore previous registry later.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting suggestion. Except I am not sure whether it is OK to change only one instance (there are nine of them) - it might be that some of these must match each other. Besides, maybe something else refers to that entry in the registry that I will change, therefore creating some system instability...